# How to group items from array of objects on a carousel using map function in React

Tags: reactjs

Problem:- I want to display 4 objects from an array of objects at a time inside a single carousel card in a row column group.

My Code:-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";

//Constants
import Constants from "../../../constants";

const HomeSearchCard = (props) => {
  const [showCarouselModal, setShowCarouselModal] = useState(false);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  const items = Constants.DOCTORS_DETAILS.filter((data) => {
    if (searchValue == null) return data;
    else if (
      data.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()) ||
      data.location.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
    ) {
      return data;
    }
  }).map((data) => {
    return (
      <div className={style.search_result}>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div
              className={`${style.search_result_part_1}`}
            >
              <div className={`${style.search_result_img_name_sec}`} onClick={() => setShowCarouselModal(true)}>
                <img src={data.imageUrl} />
                <p>{data.name}</p>
              </div>
              <div className={`${style.search_result_img_name_sec}`}>
                <img src={data.imageUrl} />
                <p>{data.name}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div
              className={`${style.search_result_part_1}`}
            >
              <div className={`${style.search_result_img_name_sec}`} onClick={() => setShowCarouselModal(true)}>
                <img src={data.imageUrl} />
                <p>{data.name}</p>
              </div>
              <div className={`${style.search_result_img_name_sec}`}>
                <img src={data.imageUrl} />
                <p>{data.name}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className={`${style.home_search_card}`}>
      <div className={`${style.search_box}`}>
        <input
          type="text"
          className={`${style.search_box_form}`}
          placeholder="Browse by location or name"
          onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
        />
        <a href="/#">
          <img src={SearchIcon} alt="" placeholder="blurred" />
        </a>
      </div>

      <div className={`${style.carousel_part1}`}>
        <Carousel
        showStatus={false}
        showThumbs={false}
        showArrows={true}
        infiniteLoop={true}
        interval={3000}
        autoPlay={false}
        >
          {items}
        </Carousel>
        </div>

      <div className={`${style.small_cards_modal_box}`}>
            <HomeInfoCarouselModel
              show={showCarouselModal}
              onHide={() => setShowCarouselModal(false)}
              selectedItem={0}
            />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomeSearchCard;
```

The object from which i am fetching the data ie Constants.DOCTOR_DETAILS

```
const DOCTORS_DETAILS = [
    {
        id: 0,
        category: "first",
        imageUrl: "https://www.twinhealth.com/static/1aff4c984d2664f9eb619084c26a8a15/8a02e/Dr.-Banshi-Saboo-With-Border.png",
        name: "Dr.Banshi Saboo",
        location: "Ahmedabad, India",
        text: "Dr.Banshi Saboo is a Chief Diabetologist & Chairman of Diabetes Care & Hormone Clinic at Ahmedabad. He has done a Ph.D in Phenotyping & Genotyping of young Diabetic in India"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        category: "first",
        imageUrl: "https://www.twinhealth.com/static/9a0698eb1308a40ee82fa3a6bf5b993b/8a02e/Dr.-Kakalee-K-Saha-With-Border.png",
        name: "Dr.Kakalee K Saha",
        location: "Mumbai, India",
        text: "Dr.Kakalee K Saha is a consultant diabetologist with over 10 years of experience inpatient treatment. She is currently the Medical Director in lifespan diabetes and cardiometabolic clinics."
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        category: "first",
        imageUrl: "https://www.twinhealth.com/static/f035f31c4b20f782c709d4e5d6c71a7a/8a02e/Dr.-Shuchin-Bajaj-With-Border.png",
        name: "Dr.Shuchin Bajaj",
        location: "New Delhi, India",
        text: "Dr. Shuchin is a highly qualified medical scholar and is the Founder Director of Ujala Cygnus Hospitals.",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        category: "first",
        imageUrl: "https://www.twinhealth.com/static/b6a24dca5a9661a00201538e4d406a1f/8a02e/Dr.-Mala-Dharmalingam-With-Border.png",
        name: "Dr. Mala Dharmalingam",
        location: "Bangalore, India",
        text: "Dr. Mala Dharmalingam is an expert Endocrinologist and Diabetologist and has been involved in a vast number of global clinical trials and research studies, in various capacities."
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        category: "second",
        imageUrl: "https://www.twinhealth.com/static/ca880a0603ed977b4ad1d37be3bd9d19/8a02e/Dr.-Paramesh-Shamanna-With-Border.png",
        name: "Dr.Paramesh Shamanna",
        location: "Bangalore, India",
        text: "Dr. Paramesh Shamanna is a leading diabetologist with over 30 years of expertise in Diabetology and Internal Medicine. "
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        category: "second",
        imageUrl: "https://www.twinhealth.com/static/3ac54a6667ff9ca1d0a3881d39303afb/8a02e/Dr.-Rakesh-Kumar-Sahay-With-Border.png",
        name: "Dr. Rakesh Kumar Sahay",
        location: "Hyderabad, India",
        text: "Dr. Rakesh Kumar Sahay is a Diabetologist and Endocrinologist and has been the Principal Investigator for several multi-centric multi-national clinical trials of drugs for diabetes, hypertension and hyperlipidemia."
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        category: "second",
        imageUrl: "https://www.twinhealth.com/static/37204a3e55c9587339926c0a07a1a152/8a02e/Dr.-Rohit-Warrier-With-Border.png",
        name: "Dr.Rohit Warrier",
        location: "Bangalore, India",
        text: "Dr. Rohit Warrier has more than 10 years of experience, currently working as a Consultant Diabetologist at Magna Centre for Obesity, Diabetes and Endocrinology, Apollo sugar clinic and Motherhood hospital Bangalore"
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        category: "second",
        imageUrl: "https://www.twinhealth.com/static/276bd178c97c8af7630343ecac0f06f4/8a02e/Dr.-Sarath-Honnatti-With-Border.png",
        name: "Dr. Sharat Honnatti",
        location: "Bangalore, India",
        text: "Dr Sharat Honnatti is an expert Diabetologist & Endocrinologist with 16 years of experience and has done multiple courses in the Management of Diabetes Mellitus and Gestational Diabetes."
    },
];
```

NOTE:- Search functionality is also enabled. I am using **"react-responsive-carousel"**.

END RESULT:- Like this i want to populate my data on UI side:-

[image: Finally like this i want to show on UI side]

Please Help..!!
Thank You

Comment: Hi There. Consider adding a reproducible demo using http://codesandbox.io/.

Comment: What is your issue? If it's just having 4 items from a large array, just use `Array.slice(0, 4)`

Comment: It is carousel. I want to show data as a pair of four @dbuchet

Comment: Why don't you create carousel slides of four items?
ie: If you have 14 items, you create 4 slides. 4 items in slide 1. 4 items in slide 2, 4 items in slide 3 et 2 items in slide 4. So your carousel have 4 `div` and not `14`

Comment: @ dbuchet search functionality is also there. If i will do this then search will work on all the 14 items or on just 4 items.?

Comment: @dbuchet Will you please help me with the code..?

Comment: With these starts, you should be able to : `const numberOfSlides = numberOfItems / 4` `const inSlide = itemIndex / 4` `const posInSlide = itemIndex % 4`